# How to find out which process created a particular file?

Tags: process, files

I know that you can use `lsof` (in Linux at least) to check which process has got a particular file opened currently, but is there anyway to find out which process created a particular file originally? Or even which process wrote/modified a particular file most recently?

Comment: I don't think there's a generic way to do this unless you're using iwatch or something, and, even then, it would be a timestamp thing. Is there a specific file you're worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auditd would help with this. See http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/ for an introduction.